# How can I be notified when I get a new connection with netcat?

Tags: macos, command-line

So basically, when I am listening with netcat (`nc -l 1337`), how can I be notified when I get a new connection? Rather than looking back and forth at my terminal window.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47597461/4703819

Comment: @Allan What about `|tee ` to split stdout and send it to a named pipe. A second command could tail the named pipe / notifying in terminal perhaps?